# How to add multiple strings to a set in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. When I added a string with `add()` function, it worked well. But when I tried to add multiple strings, it treated them as character items.

```
>>> set1 = {'a', 'bc'}
>>> set1.add('de')
>>> set1
set(['a', 'de', 'bc'])
>>> set1.update('fg', 'hi')
>>> set1
set(['a', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'de', 'bc'])
>>>
```

The results I wanted are `set(['a', 'de', 'bc', 'fg', 'hi'])`

Does this mean the `update()` function does not work for adding strings?

The version of Python used is: Python 2.7.1

Comment: Try set1.update(['fg', 'hi']).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`update` treats its arguments as sets. Thus supplied string `'fg'` is implicitly converted to a set of 'f' and 'g'.

Comment: `set.update()` will take any iterable and doesn't convert its arguments to sets. The problem is, strings are iterable and yield their characters.

Answer (score 47):

You gave `update()` multiple iterables (strings are iterable) so it iterated over each of those, adding the items (characters) of each. Give it one iterable (such as a list) containing the strings you wish to add.

```py
set1.update(['fg', 'hi'])
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's something fun using pipe equals ( |= )...

```
>>> set1 = {'a', 'bc'}
>>> set1.add('de')
>>> set1
set(['a', 'de', 'bc'])
>>> set1 |= set(['fg', 'hi'])
>>> set1
set(['a', 'hi', 'de', 'fg', 'bc'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using `set1.update( ['fg', 'hi'] )` or `set1.update( {'fg', 'hi'} )`

Each item in the passed in list or set of strings will be added to the set